# c++ container contents traits confusion

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I want to be able to select a different class to instantiate at compile time based on the type of contents of a container class. Both Clang and GCC give errors for the code below so I expect there is something wrong with it, even though it behaves correctly using Visual Studio. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template <class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
  typedef T type;
};

struct a {};
struct b {};

struct a_container {
  typedef a contents_type;
};

struct b_container {
  typedef b contents_type;
};

template <class T>
struct is_an_a { enum { value = false }; };

template <>
struct is_an_a<a> { enum { value = true }; };

template <class container_type>
struct container_traits {
  typedef typename container_type::contents_type value_type;
};

template <class container_type>
struct is_an_a_container {
  enum { value = typename is_an_a<typename container_traits<container_type>::value_type>::value };
};

template<class container_type, class enable = void>
struct S {
  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "Not an A\n";
  }
};

template<class container_type>
struct S<container_type, typename enable_if<is_an_a_container<container_type>::value>::type> {
  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "Got an A\n";
  }
};


int main() {
  S<a_container>()();
  S<b_container>()();

  return 0;
}
```

From Visual Studio, the output is:

```
Got an A
Not an A
```

GCC fails with:

```
35: error: expected `(' before '}' token
```

Whilst Clang fails with:

```
35 : error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

I can work round the problem by inlining the definition of `is_an_a_container` into the second version of `S` (e.g. below), but it seems to me a little more obscure and I'd like to understand the error.

```
template<class container_type>
struct S<container_type, typename enable_if<is_an_a<typename container_traits<container_type>::value_type>::value>::type> {
  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "Got an A\n";
  }
};
```

Or maybe there is a neater solution to achieving the goal? NB: I have to use the `container_traits`.

Comment: `typename is_an_a<...>::value` wtf?

Comment: `is_an_a<T>::value` is not a type name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class container_type>
struct is_an_a_container {
  enum { value = typename is_an_a<typename conntainer_traits<container_type>::value_type>::value };
                 ^^^^^^^^                                                                  ^^^^^ // this is not a type
};
```

Just remove the typename

```
template <class container_type>
struct is_an_a_container {
  enum { value = is_an_a<typename conntainer_traits<container_type>::value_type>::value };

};
```